# Is this question "off-topic"?

Tags: discussion

Regarding Stack Overflow question *[How can I include multiple patterns with Info-Zip, 7-Zip, or Tar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69274185/how-can-i-include-multiple-patterns-with-info-zip-7-zip-or-tar)*:

This is a programming-related question.

> I'm using command-line tools in a program, because compression tools available in function libraries are asynchronous, so there isn’t any reliable way to know when the process is finished. People use unreliable and sloppy methods like checking to see if the compression progress dialog is still open. That includes "Scripting" and "[Windows Script Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)", and "Shell32".

> The command-line tools are synchronous, so it's easy to reliably determine when they are finished.

It's a reasonable, constrained question. I showed an attempt to solve it myself three times. I followed "How do I ask a good question?" I sum up my entire question in one sentence. My grammar is good. My title is concise and functional. I introduced the problem before code. I applied good tags. I'm not asking for product endorsements. I respond to feedback.

> "if your question generally covers software tools commonly used by
> programmers"  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Yes. "and is a practical, answerable problem" - Yes, highly germane. Software development is my usage. Scripting is software development. "…then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" Great! "Some questions aren't generally a good fit: debugging, can no longer be reproduced, homework help, product recommendation, customer support, legal, general computing, network admin." No, no, no, no, no, no, no, and no.

Stack Overflow accepts questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers". Compression tools are used by programmers all the time. Command line tools aren't typically used by end-users doing general computing. A search on Stack Overflow for "file compression" yields over 25,000 results. Obviously, those questions were accepted. Compression isn't "off-topic".

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=file+compression

The guidelines do not exclude questions which overlap general purpose programming. The purpose of the guideline is to exclude questions which are exclusively about general-purpose computing. [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is used for both programming and general purpose computing. That doesn't make PowerShell questions "off-topic.

There are over 4,000 questions about [7-Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip). In some, programming isn't even mentioned. Why weren't they closed?

*[Update 7z archive with contents of an unextracted 7z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698550/update-7z-archive-with-contents-of-an-unextracted-7z)*

*[7-Zip command to create and extract a password-protected ZIP file on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160254/7-zip-command-to-create-and-extract-a-password-protected-zip-file-on-windows)*

The ultimate gauge is: Is this about programming? Answer: Yes.

Comment: Why would a question about the appropriateness of a question get downvoted? That makes no sense.

Comment: This is meta, and votes here often mean agreement or disagreement. Note that you've not really asked a question. You seem to have merely stated your opinion on the matter. So you're more likely to get votes that agree or disagree with that opinion. You should also be aware of [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect?r=SearchResults&s=1|86.7979)

Comment: Not all powershell questions are off topic, just like not all compression questions are. That doesn't mean none are.

Comment: @Scratte The title of my post is a question.

Comment: @KevinB This question is programming-related.

Comment: The question was closed. A question related to programming was deemed "off-topic". That's wrong.

Comment: The end line of your "Question" is "The ultimate gauge is: Is this about programming? **Answer: Yes.**" and the entire post looks like it's leading up to it. Note: This can go a few ways. 1. You listen to what people say here with openness. This path is usually fruitful. 2. You don't but keep arguing that you are right. That path usually does not end well for the poster.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree. You do have a programming problem, but you chose to instead use applications to solve them rather than what is available to whatever language you're using is. If your question was instead "How do i do X in Y language and reliably know when it's done," possibly also outlining the kind of solutions you don't want and why, it'd most certainly be a programming question even if the only viable solution in the end was using other apps to do it.

Comment: The question on main is asking a general computing question, which is off-topic. The votes (including mine) were unanimously for that reason, so it should appear in the close-banner.

Comment: @Scratte I am open to feedback. That doesn't mean i'm required to agree. People here have failed to respond to my points.

Comment: "You're wrong" isn't a point. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The thing I would recommend that you do at this point is to *not argue*, but take in the feedback as it's given. Then try to see it from those point of views. The end result of what happens to your post on main is not going to change by arguing your point of view more than you already did.

Comment: Your question doesn't become "programming related" just because you later want to do something in your code with the results of that question. Important is what that question is focused on and that's the usage of command-line tools.

Comment: @KevinB I never said "you're wrong". To reiterate: My application is programming, because other programming tools don't fulfill the requirement, which i explained. My explanation was disregarded. I pointed out Powershell overlaps general computing, but Powershell questions aren't excluded. Point disregarded. I pointed out other questions re 7z -- point ignored. I explained my position with logic and examples -- i never said "you're wrong". However, the response i've gotten is simply "you're wrong".

Comment: Regarding your latest edit, there are unfortunately quite a few open questions on the site that are off-topic by the current standards. Some of them were posted when the standards were different, and some simply didn't get curated at the time. They're still off-topic though, and do get closed when noticed.

Comment: @Scratte "I would recommend that you do at this point is to not argue" -Because?

Comment: not directly, but any time anyone suggests the post is off topic, your answer is effectively, no it isn't. that's... not going to convince anyone of anything productive.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not deluded into thinking that will change the outcome in this case, but I maintain my right to try to persuade others, or at least insist they explain themselves and respond to my points. Maybe when they respond to my points, i'll agree with them. Or, maybe others will read this and say "John's right, this question shouldn't have been closed", and thereby influence general opinion.

Comment: @cigien What's the plan to remove all off-topic questions? Any plan?

Comment: Because the best you can hope for now is to understand what people are saying to you. Multiple people have explained why your post isn't a good fit. That's your take away. You could reach a point where you say "Oh! I see. I'm just using command line tools in sequence, and that's not actually considered programming. Is there anything I can do to change my Question, so it is on topic?"

Comment: @Scratte The best i can hope for is everyone to understand each other. This goes both ways -- i don't know why you think it only goes one way. I'm happy to end a discussion when i'm satisfied that my points were responded to, even i don't agree. How about you stop telling me when to talk and what to hope for? Stop policing my conversation. You posted you're opinion on this question. That's all that's needed.

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any workable plan to close (which is what I assume you mean by "remove") all off-topic questions. This would be quite difficult to achieve; there are simply too many questions, and not enough curators, to attempt something on that scale. In fact, the largest curation effort I'm aware of (i.e. SOCVR) actively restricts closing questions that are too old. Also, in case you're trying to make this argument, the existence of other off-topic questions on the site doesn't make all off-topic questions exempt from closure.

Comment: @cigien "the existence of other off-topic questions on the site doesn't make all off-topic questions exempt from closure" - Perhaps, but it does make the policy meaningless and arbitrary, and enforcement of the policy meaningless and arbitrary.

Comment: That may be the case, but it is current policy, so it must be followed. Of course, if you feel the policy is problematic/pointless for whatever reasons, and if you feel it should be removed/changed/etc, that's perfectly valid, and you can have that discussion. This particular meta post, which is about a specific question on main, is not the appropriate place to have that discussion though. Feel free to make a meta post about policy, but please do some research on what has already been covered, if you choose to do so.

Comment: How is a question without a line of code, or mention of a programming language, about programming?  It appears to be about how to use common command line tools.  If it's actually about how to call those tools from a programming language, then ask that.

Comment: Not sure why it hasn't been suggested yet, but [Super User](https://superuser.com/) sounds like a great place for this question instead, since people seem to generally disagree with you about it being "programming-related". A [quick search](https://superuser.com/search?q=info-zip) reveals existing questions about info-zip and command line tools, you might consider giving that a go.

Comment: @johnywhy what Scratte was trying to hint at is, in more detail, described in a FAQ Q&A with a self-explanatory title "[How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/786798)". Approaching meta with "I am right and you are all wrong" is usually counter-productive to one's cause (I've participated in enough discussions like this here to speak from experience). It does not really matter whether you are, in fact, right or wrong. I know, it sucks, but that's how, in my view, the humanity works. The less confrontation-y the pitch, the better usually :)

Comment: As for the off-topicness of your question, you see, now that we have several sites where things like this can be on-topic ( the 25K questions you mentioned are here due to various reasons: many were asked when the question count was much smaller, some - when SO was *the* site of the network, some - when the community itself was much smaller and acting more like a startup optimistic about its future ), cases like this are, at best, borderline. Thus, many community members hold strong, and sometimes polar opposite opinions on what is, and what is not acceptable. It does not help that the [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] rules are not well-defined (I'd say outright vague) so they support many possible interpretations. I can't comment on your specific case as I am not an SME, but please do bear all this in mind when approaching Meta.

Comment: Finally, is this *that* big of a deal to you where it is asked? Folks over on Super User are likely to be more knowledgeable when it comes to shell scripting (not to undermine the competency of our folks), and it is likely to be better received due to lower traffic. SO is presently facing an identity crisis every monolith application faces at some point when it needs to live with parts of the app being refactored into focused modules resulting in asking questions similar to years being more akin to a flip of a coin rather than a consistent experience.

Answer (score 5):

In the context of you writing a shell script to execute this, you'd have a point about this being about programming.  But from this, you're just trying to run the commands.

I wonder if Unix and Linux would be a better place than this.

Comment: As explained in the post, I'm writing program code to execute these commands. That's programming. This is on a Windows platform.

Comment: At a glance, I don't *see* program code.  You only show us the command prompt that you're executing. To be perfectly fair though, even if it were the case that you were to whip together a script to do this, the *root* of your problem is still with the individual applications and not any of the code you've written, since you've isolated the problem enough to pinpoint that it's with the way you invoke zip, tar and 7z.

Comment: There are 25,000+ questions on SO about compression. Are they off-topic? There are over 4,000 questions about 7z. In some, programming isn't even mentioned. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698550/update-7z-archive-with-contents-of-an-unextracted-7z https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160254/7-zip-command-to-create-and-extract-a-password-protected-zip-file-on-windows

Comment: Yes, and that's why it's confusing because it concern both website. So, such as it has more visibility on SO and can be on both, I think it can be on SO

Comment: @Elikill58 The question was closed. This was clearly a programming-related question. It shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: @joh The question you *meant* to ask (but preemptively rejected) could have well been on-topic. The question you *did* ask is about the command line interface of general purpose tools, and it is off-topic. As a general rule of thumb: Whenever you cannot find a programming language tag to use for your question you should reconsider whether it belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok, @IInspectable.